# How to change page via login as user and admin

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, admin-menu, add-submenu-page

I am using WordPress and I'm trying to develop eCommerce website using [WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/).

When a user logs in I want to show the following in the menu-bar:

- Product
- Category
- Users profile
- Orders
- Cart

Then, when a vendor or seller login, it will show:

- Vendor's profile
- Dashboard
- Orders,
- Products
- Payment options

  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Were you able to resolve your question?

Answer (score 0):

This plugin will allow you to display your menu items based on the user role on your WordPress site: [Nav Menu Roles](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nav-menu-roles/). If you have a link in the menu that you only want to show to your vendors only, you can toggle that in the *Menu* page:
[image]